# How to calculate sum of digits of 3^1002 using java or c?

Tags: java, c++, c

Since the data types in java or c cannot handle such large number.What is the logic that i can use to find the sum of the digits?

Comment: use `java.math.BigInteger`

Comment: For C or C++ Google for any of the bignum libraries.

Comment: In C++ use a library such as GMP or MPIR. Both open source.

Comment: When you say sum of digits do you mean eg sum of digits 512 =5+1+2, them your 3^1002 "number" isn't really a number at all. Its more of a string than anything else and could be processed as such, taking each part in turn

Comment: Using BigInteger is not too localized at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
BigInteger big = BigInteger.valueOf(3).pow(1002)
```

[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers. All operations behave as if
>   BigIntegers were represented in two's-complement notation (like Java's
>   primitive integer types). BigInteger provides analogues to all of
>   Java's primitive integer operators, and all relevant methods from
>   java.lang.Math. Additionally, BigInteger provides operations for
>   modular arithmetic, GCD calculation, primality testing, prime
>   generation, bit manipulation, and a few other miscellaneous
>   operations.

You want to add sum of digits in 3^1002.Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    BigInteger big = BigInteger.valueOf(3).pow(1002);
    String s = big.toString();
    System.out.println("3^1002 :-" + big);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));

    }
    System.out.println("Sum of digits = "+sum);
}
```

Output:

```
3^1002 :-11898637375327259732014097337769299293688798294769333508984283314041457376120344095867004824655472557675187999271853241203558591238905570206788084527321583066248582026784887234902132968060683571469513601058297562370160530340607849942554095557486780070414555603129323099649923489573350062357188314294245225987472417074007240612055747584770991072267007636764090438484359179546617239448259650885170465292981543834807042949776925329153470838724492488095529295189557924920125696980009
Sum of digits = 2214
```

Comment: That's a start, but it doesn't get you the sum of digits.

Comment: there's a formula for this exact question, no need to do it by hand. it's (1-3^(N+1))/(1-3)

Comment: @TedHopp I added code for sum of digits.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean I dont understand your formula what is it for?

Comment: @vlad-ardelean - That's the sum of the numbers from 1 to 3^N, not the sum of digits of 3^N. Achintya - now you get my +1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigInteger` to calculate numbers that are too large for the primitives - it contains the needed basic mathematical functions for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
int baseNum = 3;
int power = 1002;
BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(baseNum).pow(power + 1).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(baseNum - 1));
System.out.println(bigInt);
```